# Button always in disabled state

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-foundation

I've got a button with a simple command binding on my view:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ShellViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext> 
    ...
    <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCoolCommand}" Content="Execute" />
```

And the vm:

```
public class ShellViewModel : ObservableObject {

    private RelayCommand _doSomethingCoolCommand;

    public ICommand DoSomethingCoolCommand {
        get {
            return _doSomethingCoolCommand ??
                (_doSomethingCoolCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomethingCool));
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingCool() { ... }
```

However, the button is disabled at application/view startup, and I can't get it enabled. I've tried passing a command execution evaluation to the `RelayCommand` and also set `IsEnabled` on the view. Am I missing something?

---

**Edit**

RelayCommand and ObservableObject are from the *mvvm foundation* project, as stated in the tags. Link: https://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com

Comment: What RelayCommand version you are using here? Is this your own custom class?

Comment: @RohitVats No, it's from the MVVM foundation project. See: https://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvvmFoundation/MvvmFoundation.Wpf/RelayCommand.cs

Comment: Only reason would have been if `CanExecute` delegate returns false for DoSomethingCoolCommand but you don't have provided that delegate. So, it should be true always. Is this complete code? Do you have CanExecute delegate OR do you have some default template defined for button in application?

Comment: Is the parent enabled?

Comment: @RohitVats No, I don't have that delegate and I'm also not using a template. It's just a small demo app I've made to try a few things out when I noticed that the buttons are not working. :(

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus The parent is a stack panel with no styles defined.

Comment: @RohitVats I've tried setting the delegate to '() => true', but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does `new RelayCommand(c => DoSomethingCool())` make any difference?

Comment: @paul You mean "() => DoSomethingCool()", right? No, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @xvdiff - In posted code nothing seems wrong. Can you upload small sample replicating your problem somewhere we can have a look?

Comment: @RohitVats Where? Throwing everything in a pastebin or is there something like plunkr for .Net applications?

Comment: If it's a small one, pastebin would be good Or some link to dropbox, gitHub would be good too.

Comment: CanExecute on the command is returning false, and CanExecuteChanged is never fired.  First, find out why CanExecute is returning false.  Next, find out how to change that. Finally, figure out how the command can fire CanExecuteChanged so that the button re-checks CanExecute.  The Aristocrats.

Comment: The only things I can think of to cause such behavior based on just the limited code posted is either _doSomethingCoolCommand.CanExecute is false, or a global style is disabling buttons. I suspect it's the first case here. Is `_doSomethingCoolCommand` set to something anywhere else in the code? And is the code shown here the exact code that creates the command in your application?

Comment: @Will: That was was thinking too at first, but he never sets an canexecute call back in his constructor, so its always null and should by default MVVM Light implementation return true `return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if any of the Buttons parents has it's state to disabled? This would also disable all child controls.

On a side-note:

You never seem to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` and it's not implemented in the `RelayCommand` class, just the registration of events, as seen [here](https://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvvmFoundation/MvvmFoundation.Wpf/RelayCommand.cs). ICommand or RelayCommand never does invalidate update it's state by default. You got to do this. Either by calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` which will suggest a requery of all registered Commands (since action in button 1, can have influence on many other commands.

For Example, there could be a `IsProcessing` property and when it's value is changed you could call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to update the state of all other Commands.